# error Unexpected mutation of "todo" prop in vue.js (I'm using vue3)

Tags: vue.js

I'm making a *todo* app in *vue.js* which has a component `TodoItem`

```js
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-completed':todo.completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" @change="markCompleted" />
      {{todo.task}}
      <button class="del">x</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todo"],
  methods: {
    markCompleted() {
      this.todo.completed = true
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

todo prop that I'm passing:

```js
{
  id:1,
  task:'todo 1',
  completed:false
}
```

but it is throwing an error **error  Unexpected mutation of "todo" prop**

Comment: You shouldn't mute `this.todo`, you should emit an event and mutate that in the parent component.

Comment: if you're talking about doing this ```change="$emit(markCompleted)"``` it ain't' working it is throwing same error

Comment: @arieljuod Why should you not mutate in the child component? It's much easier than doing it in the parent

Comment: When you have a component that receives an object through a prop, the parent is the one controlling that object, if you update it inside the child you break the synchronization of the state, check the docs here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow, it says `you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Method 1 (Vue 2.3.0+) - From your parent component, you can pass prop with [sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

**Parent Component**

```
<TodoItem v-for="todo in todoList" :key="todo.id" todo_prop.sync="todo">
```

**Child Component**

```
    <template>
      <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-completed':todo.completed}">
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" @change="markCompleted" />
          {{todo.task}}
          <button class="del">x</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "TodoItem",
      props: ["todo_prop"],
      data() {
         return {
            todo: this.todo_prop
         }
      },
      methods: {
        markCompleted() {
          this.todo.completed = true
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**Method 2** - Pass props from parent component without sync modifier and emit an event when the value changed. For this method, everything else is similar as well. Just need to emit an event when the todo item changed to completed.

The code is untested. Apologies if anything does not work.

Comment: sync modifier has been deprecated in vue 3

Answer (score 6):

Mutating a prop locally is now considered an anti-pattern, e.g. declaring a prop and then setting `this.myProp = 'someOtherValue'` in the component. Due to the new rendering mechanism, whenever the parent component re-renders, the child component’s local changes will be overwritten.

Solution: You can store it as local data.

```
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todo"],
  data() {
    return {
      todoLocal: this.todo,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    markComplete() {
      this.todoLocal.completed = !this.todoLocal.completed;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the core principles of VueJS is that child components never mutate a `prop`.

> All props form a **one**-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around.

If you wish to have the child component update `todo.completed`, you have two choices:

#### Use `.sync` modifier (Recommended)

This approach will require a bit of change to your `props`. You can [read more about it here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

**Parent component**

```
<template>
<div>
  ...
  <todo-item :task="nextTodo.task" :completed.sync="nextTodo.completed"/>
</div>
</template>
```

**Child component**

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-completed':completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" @change="markCompleted" />
      {{task}}
      <button class="del">x</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["task", "completed"],
  methods: {
    markCompleted() {
      this.$emit('update:completed', true)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

#### Use a custom event

Vue allows you set up listeners in your parent for events that the child will emit. Your child component can use this mechanism to ask the parent to change things. In fact, the above `.sync` modifier is doing exactly this behind the scenes.

**Parent component**

```
<template>
<div>
  ...
  <todo-item :todo="nextTodo" @set-completed="$value => { nextTodo.completed = $value }/>
</div>
</template>
```

**Child component**

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-completed':todo.completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" @change="markCompleted" />
      {{todo.task}}
      <button class="del">x</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todo"],
  methods: {
    markCompleted() {
      this.$emit('set-completed', true)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For me to fix this problem I store props in todos data im watching brad vue tutorials and i get this error this is my actual codes and its working.

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{ 'is-complete': todo.completed }">
    <p>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-on:change="markComplete(todo.completed)"
        v-bind:checked="todo.completed"
      />
      {{ todo.title }}
      <!-- <button @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)" class="del">x</button> -->
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TodoItem',
  props: ['todo'],
  data() {
    return {
      todos: this.todo,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    markComplete(isComplete) {
      this.todos.completed = !isComplete
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.todo-item {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted;
}
.is-complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.del {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to achieve n-deep prop binding in **Vue 3** is to wrap your prop with a simple computed property.  This is an example of a component that will communicate changes to it's `selected` property to it's parent--who is ultimately responsible for storing the state.

```vue
<template>
  <!-- In this example my-child-component also has a "selected" prop -->
  <my-child-component v-model:selected="syncSelectedId" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  components: { MyChildComponent },
  props: {
    selected: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:selected'],
  setup(props, context) {
    const syncSelectedId = computed<string>({
      get() {
        return props.selected;
      },
      set(newVal: string) {
        context.emit('update:selected', newVal);
      },
    });
    return {
      syncSelectedId,
    }
  }
});
```

So to re-iterate: With this strategy the highest level parent is the holder of the state.  The code above assumes that there is a parent component in the hierarchy (so this component is just a "middle-man").

Then `my-child-component` can simply emit its own `update:selected` event to cause the state to change.  That child will be updated appropriately through it's prop after the emit event causes the parent chain to propagate that change up (through emits) and then back down the component hierarchy (through props).

If you wanted to you could modify the code above to make it the "owner" of the state:

```vue
<template>
  <my-child-component v-model:selected="selected" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  components: { MyChildComponent },
  setup(props, context) {
    const selected = ref('');
    return {
      selected,
    }
  }
});
```

And now of course you won't run into the "Unexpected mutation of X prop" error.

Another option is to have a prop that serves as a "default value" for a given state:

```vue
<template>
  <my-child-component v-model:selected="selected" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  components: { MyChildComponent },
  props: {
    defaultSelected: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  setup(props, context) {
    const selected = ref(props.defaultSelected);
    return {
      selected,
    }
  }
});
```

And in this code above keep in mind that `selected` will NOT change if `defaultSelected` changes after the component has been initialized.

And lastly it's worth noting that you could write more sophisticated code to detect if a property is supplied--and if not use an internal state variable to store the value.  I use this pattern for re-usable components that could be embedded in places where the parent wants to control the state OR in places where the parent is happy to delegate the storage of the state to the child:

```vue
<template>
  <!-- In this example my-child-component also has a "selected" prop -->
  <my-child-component v-model:selected="syncSelectedId" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  components: { MyChildComponent },
  props: {
    selected: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: null // Important: parent MUST pass non-null value if it wants to control state
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:selected'],
  setup(props, context) {
    // This is state storage used if prop.selected is not provided
    const _selected = ref('');
    const syncSelectedId = computed<string>({
      get() {
        return props.selected === null ? _selected.value : props.selected;
      },
      set(newVal: string) {
        if (props.selected !== null) {
          // Using prop.selected as the driving model...
          if (newVal !== props.selected) {
            // We need to set to empty string (never null)
            context.emit('update:selectedId', (newVal == null ? '' : newVal));
          }
        } else { // Storing selection state with _selectedId
          if (newVal !== _selected.value) {
            _selected.value = newVal == null ? '' : newVal;
            context.emit('update:selected', _selected);
          }
        }
      },
    });
    return {
      syncSelectedId,
    }
  }
});
```

This last example is tricky... it gives special meaning to `null` and requires that you be very mindful of potential values of your state.  In my example empty string is my representation for "no selection" and null is used as a flag for "no parent model of this state".

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a prop from inside a component - they are meant to be set by the parent only. It's a one-directional communication path.

You can try one of two things - either move your logic for detecting a todo has been completed to the parent, or feed the prop into a new variable in the data() lifecycle hook (this will only happen when the component is loaded for the first time, so you won't be able to update from outside the component, if that's important for your use case).

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, property mutation is now deprecated and parent properties are overwritten when the parent component renders its DOM.

Here's the official [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html?redirect=true#Prop-Mutation-deprecated) about it. We can still achieve this in multiple possible ways. Through a data property, a computed property, and component events.

When we want to pass this value back to the parent component as well as the nested child component of the current child component, `using a data property` would be useful as shown in the following example.

**Example**:
Calling your child component from the parent component like this.

Parent component:

```html
<template>
  <TodoItem :todoParent="todo" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      todo: {
        id:1,
        task:'todo 1',
        completed:false
      }
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-completed':todo.completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" @change="markCompleted" />
      {{todo.task}}
      <button class="del">x</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todoParent"],
  data() {
    return {
      todo: this.todoParent,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    markCompleted() {
      this.todo.completed = true
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Even you can pass this property to the nested child component and it won't give this error/warning.

Other use cases when you only need this property sync between parent and child component. It can be achieved using the `sync` modifier from Vue. `v-model` can also be useful. Many other examples are available in this question thread.

**Example2**: using [component events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html).
We can `emit` the event from the child component as below.

Parent component:

```html
<template>
  <TodoItem :todo="todo" @markCompletedParent="markCompleted" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      todo: {
        id:1,
        task:'todo 1',
        completed:false
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    markCompleted() {
      this.todo.completed = true
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-completed':todo.completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" @change="markCompleted" />
      {{todo.task}}
      <button class="del">x</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todo"],
  methods: {
    markCompleted() {
      this.$emit('markCompletedParent', true)
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can still custom-bind events to handle this, `.sync` property extensions are considered deprecated. [In Vue3 (at least) you can and usually should use the `v-model:property` declaration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model), similar to how you bind the property to the actual input. You just need to bind the inner input with `:value` and have it emit a matching `update:property`

```
<!-- CustomInput.vue -->
<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<template>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>
```

And use thusly:

```
<CustomInput v-model="searchText" />
```