# Why do I have en error "Unexpected mutation of "modelValue" prop" in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

So i'm working with you and I have a select component, I created a modelValue prop which is an empty string, and passed it in v-model:

```
<select v-model="modelValue" @change="changeOption">
        <option 
        disabled 
        value="">
        Choose from the  list
        </option>
        <option 
        v-for="option in options" 
        :key="option.value" 
        :value="option.value">
            {{ option.name }}
        </option>
    </select>

props:{
            modelValue:{
                type: String
            },
            options:{
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            }
        }
```

But for some reason it gives an error: Unexpected mutation of "modelValue" prop.
I just started working with Vue so I'm not sure where this error could come from. I was following a tutorial and everything seemed to work there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error Unexpected mutation of "todo" prop in vue.js (I'm using vue3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688517/error-unexpected-mutation-of-todo-prop-in-vue-js-im-using-vue3)

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify a prop directly.
The best way is create a computed with get set functions and emit update inside set function.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

```
computed: {
    localModelValue: {
        get() {
            return this.modelValue
        },
        set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
        },
    },
},
```

And in the component instance declare prop as sync

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

```
:model-value.sync="..."
```

Answer (score -1):

1. create life cycle "computed"

   computed: {
   localModelValue: {
   get() {
   return this.modelValue
   },
   },
   },
2. After that change `v-model="modelValue"` to `v-model="localModelValue"`